# Is there a method in shell to ignore escape characters?

Tags: shell, escaping

In C#, there is a verbatim string so that,

```
string c = "hello \t world";               // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";              // hello \t world
```

I am new to shell script, is there a similar method in shell?

Because I have many folders with the name like "Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear", I want to know if there is a easy way to process the escape characters without write so many .

```
test.sh

director="Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear"
# any action to escape spaces, &, >   ???
hadoop fs -ls $director
```

Comment: For the shell, you can enclose the whole text within quotes instead of escaping special characters.

Comment: single quotes, using a "here doc", and you can actually put tabs and newline in the quotes without using the escape sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *definining* the specific string in your example, `Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear`, *either* double quotes *or* single quotes will work; *referring* to it later is a different story, however:

**In the *shell* (any POSIX-compatible shell), how you *refer* to a variable is just as important as how you *define* it.**

**To safely *refer* to a previously defined variable without side-effects, *enclose it in double quotes*, e.g., `"$directory"`.**

**To *define*** [a variable as] a **literal (verbatim) string**:

(By contrast, to define a variable with *embedded variable references* or *embedded command substitutions* or *embedded arithmetic expressions*, use *double* quotes (`"`).)

- If your string contains **NO *single* quotes**:

  - **Use a single-quoted string**, e.g.:

    ```
        directory='Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear'
    ```

A **single-quoted string is not subject to any interpretation by the shell**, so it's **generally the safest option for defining a *literal***. Note that the string may span multiple lines; e.g.:

```
        multiline='line 1
        line 2'
```

- If your string  **DOES contain *single* quotes** (e.g., `I'm here.`) and you want a solution that **works in *all* POSIX-compatible shells**:

  - **Break the string into multiple (single-quoted) parts and *splice in* single-quote characters**:

Note: Sadly, *single-quoted strings cannot contain single quotes, not even with escaping*.

```
        directory='I'\''m here.'
```

The string is broken into into single-quoted `I`, followed by literal `'` (escaped as an *unquoted* string as `\'`), followed by single-quoted `m here.`. By virtue of having NO spaces between the parts, the result is a *single* string containing a literal single quote after `I`.

Alternative: if you *don't mind using a multiline statement*, you can use a *quoted here document*, as described at the bottom.

- If your string  **DOES contain *single* quotes** (e.g., `I'm here.`) and you want a solution that **works in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`**:

  - Use **ANSI-C quoting**:

    ```
        directory=$'I\'m here.'
    ```

Note: As you can see, ANSI-C quoting allows for **escaping single quotes as `\'`**, but note the additional implications: other **`\<char>` sequences are subject to interpretation**, too; e.g., `\n` is interpreted as a newline character - see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

---

Tip of the hat to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), who points out that the **POSIX-compatible way of directly including a single quote in a string to be used *verbatim*** is to use **`read -r` with a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) using a *quoted* opening delimiter** (the `-r` option ensures that `\` characters in the string are treated as literals).

```
# *Any* form of quoting, not just single quotes, on the opening EOF will work.
# Note that $HOME will by design NOT be expanded.
# (If you didn't quote the opening EOF, it would.)
read -r directory <<'EOF'
I'm here at $HOME
EOF
```

- Note that here documents create *stdin* input (which `read` reads in this case). Therefore, you cannot use this technique to directly pass the resulting string as an *argument*.

Answer (score 2):

use strong quotes i.e. 'string', allowing escape char or special char for string.

> ```
> e.g. declare director='Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear'
> ```
>
> also using declare is a good practice while declaring variable.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of *expanding* `$director`.